# Find specific word and print till newline in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string and I want to match something that start with specific word and end with newline. How can this be done?

```
Website:https://www.abc1.xyz/
Product:Apparal
TM Link:https://www.abc2.xyz/
Other Link:https://www.abc3.xyz/
```

I want to extract [Website,Product,TM Link,Other Link] and save this in a CSV.
I am new to writing regular expression, I was wondering if anyone had a good solution to this that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex, two splits do the trick here too

```py
s = """Website:https://www.abc1.xyz/
Product:Apparal
TM Link:https://www.abc2.xyz/
Other Link:https://www.abc3.xyz/"""

res = [l.split(':')[0] for l in [line for line in s.split('\n')]]


with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(res))
```

If you want to get the part after the first semicolon:

```py
s = """Website:https://www.abc1.xyz/
Product:Apparal
TM Link:https://www.abc2.xyz/
Other Link:https://www.abc3.xyz/"""

res = [l.split(':', maxsplit=1)[1] for l in [line for line in s.split('\n')]]


with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(res))
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the effort.
I ran the file, it is giving this as result: ['Website', 'PTD', 'TM Link', 'Other Link'] instead of [https://www.abc1.xyz/, Apparel, https://www.abc2.xyz/,https://www.abc3.xyz/]

Comment: ```['Website', 'PTD', 'TM Link', 'Other Link']``` is the output you're asking for in your question. If you want the part after the semicolon, change the zero to a one.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, however now its returning ['https', 'Apparel', 'https', 'https']

Comment: Right, my bad. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Please mark the answer as accepted to close the question.